# Silent notification

Tags: objective-c, silentpush

Although I receive a silent notification (content-available=1) in my app, a pop up message appear all the times which should not happen. I use the OneSignal service. Could anybody assist?

Methods executed are as follows:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Many thanks

The full code shown below:

## import "AppDelegate.h"

```
        @interface AppDelegate ()

        @end

        @implementation AppDelegate


        - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
            // Override point for customization after application launch.
            
            // OneSignal Push Notifications
            self.oneSignal = [[OneSignal alloc] initWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions
                                                                appId:@"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
                                                   handleNotification:nil];


            return YES;
        }

        - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
            // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
            // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
        }

        - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
            // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
            // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
        }

        - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
            // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
        }

        - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
            // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        }

        - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
            // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        }

        // system push notification registration success callback, delegate to pushManager
        - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken {
            NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
        }

        // system push notification registration error callback, delegate to pushManager
        - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error {
            NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
        }

        -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
            NSLog(@"PUSH NOTIFICATION %@",userInfo);
            
            if([userInfo[@"aps"][@"content-available"] intValue] == 1) {
                NSLog(@"SILENT PUSH NOTIFICATION");
                if (completionHandler) {
                    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
                }
            } else {
                NSLog(@" GENERAL PUSH NOTIFICATION ");
                if (completionHandler) {
                    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
                }
            }
        }

        - (void)application:(UIApplication *) application
        handleActionWithIdentifier: (NSString *) identifier
        forRemoteNotification: (NSDictionary *) additionalData
          completionHandler: (void (^)()) completionHandler {
            
            if (completionHandler) {
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
            }
            
            
        }

        @end
```

Answer (score 0):

notification payload looks like this

```
{
    "aps": {
         "badge": 10,
         "alert": "Hello world!",
         "sound": "Default"
    }
}
```

if you not want msg banner or alert show then not add alert  key in your payload

```
{
    "aps": {
         "badge": 10,
         "sound": "Default"
    }
}
```

hope its work for you.

Comment: aps =     {
        "content-available" = 1;
    };
    custom =     {
        a =         {
            id = 3175616;
            type = article;
        };
        i = "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx";
    };

Comment: I cannot attach a photo. It is just an empty alert with an "OK" button.

Comment: @GeorgeMilissis you showing alert when notification come and when silent notification come its show blank alert ?

Comment: Exactly. You see my aps. There is nowhere "alert" or "badge" but it shows an empty alert!!! I will become crazy!

Comment: In method -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler  I just save the message in a plist to show it on demand. It is really strange.

Comment: can you show the code   didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler

Comment: Unfortunately it is too long to put here.

Comment: I cannot either go to chat due to my level, to show you the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can make unable and disable your notification by this code  .
may be help you

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    // For iOS 8 and above
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    // For iOS < 8
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```